# Firefox and MS Edge download content in hidden element (but should not)

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

The following code snippets highlights what I consider to be a bug (or is it a feature?) in MS Edge and Firefox: a PDF file is downloaded when displaying the page, even though it is hidden.

Chrome and (not surprisingly) MS Edge Chromium, do not download until the element is visible, which I what I would expect.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test Embedded PDF</title>
<body>
  <!-- ... explanation text removed ... -->
  <div style="display:none">
    <object id="pdf-view" data="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" type="application/pdf" style="width:100vw;height:100vh;"></object>
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Screenshot: On Chrome - PDF IS NOT downloaded

[image]

Screenshot: On Firefox - PDF IS downloaded, despite the fact that it is hidden

[image]

Has anyone encountered this, and is there a work-around?
Thank you

Comment: hi dear. 
I think it's kind of feature of caching these two browsers you named in your question.
both of them have access to your content. so can download any frontend content or links or file.

Comment: So instead of hiding it, leave it empty and change the innerHTML of the div when you want the object to load

Comment: Yes, I thought of that. It's just more complicated and ... annoying. Thank you for the suggestion, though.

Comment: I try to test the issue and found that MS Edge is downloading the hidden pdf file. I suggest you try to load the file dynamically if possible for you. I will try to provide feedback to Microsoft about this issue. Thanks for your understanding.